# iPad application prototyping with Flex

Tags: apache-flex, ipad, user-interface, prototype

I am thinking about iPad application prototyping with Flex (although I have never used them so far). The prototype consists of just a few newspaper-like pages with animation effects like page turning, zooming in/out, etc.

Does it make sense ? Where should I start ? What resources would you recommend ?

Answer (score 1):

Good news, FlashBuilder 4.5 supports IPhone, IPad and IPod touch applications. 
http://www.adobe.com/products/flash-builder.html

Answer (score -1):

If you want to run the prototype on iPad, it's not going to work because Flex compiles to Flash and iPad does not support Flash.

If you want to run the prototype locally on a computer, I guess it could work, although Flex does not support multitouch and other fancy iPad things. (Well, it didn't a while ago when I used it, I'm not sure about the newest versions.) But you should always test on a device, because the control sizes and such appear very different on physical devices than they do on a computer.

One great resource I recommend is LiveView at http://zambetti.com/projects/liveview/. This lets you see your computer screen on the device and even interact with controls, so that if you touch something on device, it simulates a click in computer.

Comment: Sorry, thats wrong. Flash and/or Flex can be compiled as native ios apps, and touch is supported (and that was all true in feb '11 too).